# clojure 101 combining vectors into a map

Tags: dictionary, vector, clojure, functional-programming, lisp

I'm very new to Clojure and can't seem to find a way to do something that I'm sure is trivial.  I've looked at the `assoc` function as I think this might be the answer, but can't make it work.

What I have:

```
keys => [:num, :name, :age]
people =>  [ [1, "tim", 31] [2, "bob" 33] [3, "joe", 44] ]
```

What I want to do is create a vector of maps, each map looks like

```
[ { :num 1, :name "tim", :age 31 } 
  { :num 2, :name "bob", :age 33 } 
  { :num 3, :name "joe", :age 44 } ]
```

My OO brain wants me to write a bunch of loops, but I know there is a better way I'm just a bit lost in the big API.

Comment: "My OO brain wants me to write a bunch of loops" << Loops are a characteristic of imperative programming, not OOP. The two are orthogonal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
(def ks [:num :name :age])
(def people [[1 "tim" 31] [2 "bob" 33] [3 "joe" 44]])

(map #(zipmap ks %) people)

=> ({:num 1, :name "tim", :age 31}
    {:num 2, :name "bob", :age 33}
    {:num 3, :name "joe", :age 44})
```

Notice that I used `ks` instead of `keys` for naming the keys, as `keys` is a built-in procedure in Clojure and it's a bad idea to redefine it. Also be aware that `map` returns a lazy sequence; if you absolutely need a vector, then do this:

```
(vec (map #(zipmap ks %) people))

=> [{:num 1, :name "tim", :age 31}
    {:num 2, :name "bob", :age 33}
    {:num 3, :name "joe", :age 44}]
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for and was dancing around the edges of for a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A tad bit more elegant, using [`clojure.core/partial`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/partial):

```
(map (partial zipmap keys) people)
```

And as Óscar suggested, you should use a different name for your `keys`.

Comment: Use `mapv` to match what Óscar is asking for.